# Flutter Build - Error (Xcode): Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results

Tags: flutter, xcode, build

I added a widget extension target in Xcode to use an iOS widget in Flutter, but an error is occurring in the build.

Below is information related to the error.

```
Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'Runner': CodeSign /Users/leewonhee/Desktop/student_assistant/ios/build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “Thin Binary”
○ Target 'Runner' has process command with output '/Users/leewonhee/Desktop/student_assistant/ios/build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist'
○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/leewonhee/Desktop/student_assistant/ios/build/Debug-iphoneos/flutterioswidgetExtension.appex' to '/Users/leewonhee/Desktop/student_assistant/ios/build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/PlugIns/flutterioswidgetExtension.appex'
```

Does anyone know a solution?

I tried various solutions, but the problem was the same.